# How common is 'Sweet as.' in the rest of the world?

Tags: phrases, slang, new-zealand-english

In New Zealand, we have slang 'Sweet as', which means 'That's ok', 'No problems', 'All good'.

eg.

> Sorry I'm not going to be able to make it today, my child is sick.
>
> Sweet as - can you do next week?

I'm wondering how common this phrase is in the rest of the world, and whether people understand its meaning.

Comment: I'm from the US (NYC, specifically), and I've never heard it. Though I imagine it'd be pretty easy to interpret in context.

Comment: I'm from the UK - I've certainly heard it but I can't remember where or when. It's possible I heard it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_Squad

Comment: I've never encountered it (UK)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it isn't common in either Britain or Canada.Unless it's (harrummpff) young person's slang.

Comment: It is common in Australia (but might have been brought over by some Kiwis!)

Comment: "Sweet!" is certainly an expression that was popular among those coming of age in the 80s.  But it basically meant "great", and would have been considered an inappropriate response to "my child is sick".  And of course "sweet" has been used for eons to mean "good", as in "I got a sweet deal on this used set of Encyclopedia Britannicas."

Comment: It's certainly not common where I come from (Singapore). In fact, I might misinterpret that as a compliment on my delightful derriere! :)

Comment: It seems a very twisted formula that makes no sense at all. I wonder what was really behind "sweet and "as". I guess  it was something totally different. Maybe an expression of indigenous people.

Comment: Astonishingly Urban Dictionary has an entry for "Sweet as". But they say it means good, excellent, super etc. So it seems an elliptic formula as "as sweet as honey" or something like that. The elliptic formula seems to have developed other uses.

Comment: I've heard it spoken in London - but then we have a lot of Antipodeans so that's probably why!

Comment: My 10 year old uses "That's sweet!"  regularly to indicate something is "cool" but haven't heard anyone older say it. (UK here)

Comment: I have not heard people saying "Sweet as" in India. Urban Dictionary mentions "Sweet as" as the second most common phrase used in NZ. But the meaning is not "No problem". http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sweet+as

Answer (score 4):

Being from the United States (the Midwest), I've never heard the phrase. I doubt that I would've been able to discern its meaning out of context. That said, we use quite a few idioms that begin with those words: "sweet as pie," "...honey," "...sugar," etc. Basically, it would only be used when followed by a sweet object in order to call something else "sweet" by comparison. We sure do love our similes!

For what it's worth, in the context you mention, common responses from these parts of 'Murica would probably be "Oh, you're fine," "Don't worry about it," or if you want to get really slangy, perhaps a "No prob." :)